# asp.net mvc 2.0 : route request to static resource

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, iis-7, httphandler

I want to route HTTP requests not to an action, but to a file.

**Important:** I **do have** a working solution using IIS 7.0 URL Rewriting module, but for debugging at home (no IIS 7.0) I can't use URL rewriting.

**Specific situation**
I want to point any URL that contains `/images/` to a `~/images/` folder.

Example:

```
http://wowreforge.com/images/a.png -> /images/a.png
http://wowreforge.com/Emerald Dream/Jizi/images/a.png -> /images/a.png
http://wowreforge.com/US/Emerald Dream/Jizi/images/a.png -> /images/a.png
http://wowreforge.com/characters/view/images/a.png -> /images/a.png
```

The problem stems from the fact that page "view_character.aspx" can be arrived to from multiple URLs:

```
http://wowreforge.com/?name=jizi&reaml=Emerald Dream
http://wowreforge.com/US/Emerald Dream/Jizi
```

**Context**
IIS 7.0 (integrated mode), ASP.NET MVC **2.0**

**Extra Credit Questions**

- Is it a bad idea to use ASP.NET MVC routing in this situation instead of URL rewriting?
- What handler does IIS 7.0 routes requests to physical files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably rewrite your links to images to.

```
<img src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/images/a.png") %>" />
```

That way you don't need to have your routes handle the images.

**UPDATE**
How you would do it through routing
add this entry to your RouteTable

```
routes.Add("images", new Route("{*path}", null, 
   new RouteValueDictionary(new { path = ".*/images/.*"}), 
   new ImageRouteHandler()));
```

Now you need to create an ImageRouteHandler and an ImageHandler

```
public class ImageRouteHandler : IRouteHandler
{
    public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        //you'll need to figure out how to get the physical path
        return new ImageHandler(/* get physical path */);
    }
}

public class ImageHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public string PhysicalPath { get; set; }

    public ImageHandler(string physicalPath)
    {
        PhysicalPath = physicalPath;
    }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.TransmitFile(PhysicalPath);
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return true; }
    }
}
```

This also doesn't do any caching. You can check out System.Web.StaticFileHandler in Reflector for the handler that processes static files for an Asp.Net application for a more complete implementation.

Comment: it doesn't work when html is generated by javascript. And resolving URLs in javascript files feels messy.

Comment: @user93422 messier than writing custom route handlers and polluting your route table?

Comment: definitely so. But then again, I don't know what route will look like. Regardless, I would like to know how it is done through routing.

Comment: @user93422 I've added a route based solution, but again I don't recommend it.